# C++ and JAVA functions

Tags: javascript, java, c++, function

In javascript, when I create a constructor, I can do something like this:

```
function func(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
func.name = "func";
var a = new func("a");
alert(func.name);
alert(a.name);
```

Both `func` and `new func` have the `name` prototype.
How can I do the in Java and C++? 
I know that in Java:

```
public class func {
    String name;
    public func(String text) {
        name = text;
    }
}
func a = new func("a");
System.out.println(a.name);
```

but how to do the `func.name` and how do I do that in C++?
thank!

Comment: why are you comparing all 3 ?

Comment: First step: Don't write JS in Java/C++. The whole prototype stuff doesn't exist in the latter two languages (at least not as built-in language element)

Comment: When writing Java, follow the Java coding conventions.

Comment: Java or Javascript?  They are two different languages.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommand you to review your [Object oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) knowledge for this.

Otherwise, you can use the [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) to access the field of an object, just like this

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Func {

    public:
        Func(std::string text) : name(text) {}

        std::string getName()
        {
            return name;   
        }

    private:
    std::string name;
};


int main() {

    Func f("func");
    std::cout << f.getName() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

> but how to do the func.name

You can't do that in Java.  You cannot dynamically give a name to a class or method.  Same for C++.

---

> didn't mean a name specifically. I ment for a some variable. func.func if you like.

Same answer, basically.

You cannot dynamically set *any* attributes on a class or method (or function) in Java or C++.

I guess you could *declare* a static variable, like this:

```
public class Func {
    static String fname;
    String name;
    public Func(String text) {
        name = text;
    }
}

Func a = new Func("a");
Func.fname = "funky";
System.out.println(a.name);
System.out.println(Func.fname);
```

Comment: I didn't mean a name specifically. I ment for a some variable. `func.func` if you like.

Comment: @ZivSdeor same deal.